# Security options on Google App Engine Flexible

Tags: apache-flex, google-app-engine, graniteds

I'm building a Flex application and want to know the alternatives regarding security.

1. don't want to use Spring
2. using graniteds
3. limited access application server

Comment: You means alternatives of server side technology? Including hosting solutions or not?

Answer (score 2):

In theory, since your Flex application is running on the client, a malicious user can do anything that the application can do.

Since your application is Flash, a user can decompile and deobfuscate your code and figure out which network protocol you're using -- it all depends on how much effort you've made to hide things and how determined the attacker is.

In short, verify each user action on the server side.